# How to apply diff rules of the languages in gitattributes

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

For example, the `.gitattributes` file of `lg2s` has the line `*.cs     diff=csharp`. the output of the codes

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"path\to\lg2s"))
{
    var tree1 = repo.Lookup<Commit>("a845db9").Tree;
    var tree2 = repo.Lookup<Commit>("d677741").Tree;
    var patches = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(tree1, tree2);
    foreach (var patch in patches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(patch.Patch);
    }
}
```

is (shortly)

```
diff --git a/LibGit2Sharp/RepositoryStatus.cs b/LibGit2Sharp/RepositoryStatus.cs
@@ -59,8 +59,8 @@ namespace LibGit2Sharp
```

but the output of `git bash` is (shortly)

```
diff --git a/LibGit2Sharp/RepositoryStatus.cs b/LibGit2Sharp/RepositoryStatus.cs
@@ -59,8 +59,8 @@ internal RepositoryStatus(Repository repo, StatusOptions optio
```

the second line not same.

Looks like there are an in-depth discussion `Add .gitattributes support` [libgit2/#508](http://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/508), but the PR `Add APIs for git attributes` [libgit2/#516](http://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/516) is merged or not?

How many languages were supported now?

Can we specify the rules without `gitattributes` file?

Comment: What version of Libgit2Sharp are you using?

Comment: @nulltoken last release from nuget for development environment and HEAD for research.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually an issue of diff drivers and custom function context rules for diffs, not one of attributes.

Those files do have the `diff=csharp` attribute; the problem is that the attribute doesn't mean anything to `libgit2`.

When `git` and `libgit2` generate diffs, they use regular expressions to find the name of the function in which a diff hunk occurs.  They also have a fallback rule if no regular expression is available to find the first line that did not start with whitespace.

`git` contains a [table of built in diff drivers](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/userdiff.c#L137-L151) that includes a definition of the `csharp` driver.

`libgit2` does not contain that table (as discussed [in the PR that merged diff driver support](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1642#issuecomment-19302226)) and hence has no built in notion of what pattern to use for `diff=csharp`.

Your alternatives for solving this are either:

1. Make an entry in your `.git/config` file (or your `$HOME/.gitconfig`) that implements `diff.csharp.xfuncname` with a pattern to search, or
2. Start a Pull Request to `libgit2` that imports the driver definitions.  The issue with importing (and the reason I didn't take it on) is that it will involve getting permission from the original authors of the code to relicense it for use in `libgit2`).

If you decide to start a Pull Request and you get the author of the CSharp xfuncname patterns to agree to relicense the code for `libgit2`, let me know and I'll be happy to collaborate on the actual implementation!

Comment: I'd like try to add the diff pattern for csharp, but I am very not good at C, even I don't know how to compile the `libgit2`. Could you please point out how to implement it. Thank you!

Comment: @Aimeast Would **[this](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/wiki/Building-libgit2-on-Windows)** fit your need?

Comment: @Aimeast I'm afraid this is not a great starter project for contributing C code to libgit2. There is no easy existing hook to plug the patterns from core Git into libgit2; it will require adding a new mechanism into some existing and somewhat complicated code.  Feel free to file a feature request on libgit2 (as an Issue) and we can discuss further there.

Comment: As a followup, https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2066 was merged which adds the builtin diff drivers to libgit2, so `diff=csharp` should now match the behavior of regular Git.